# What command will launch lubuntu-desktop 20.04?

Tags: lubuntu, vnc, lxqt

With either vncserver or Xorg already launched by a logged in user, without sddm, what command will launch the lubuntu 20.04 desktop?

Example for kubuntu-desktop:  `startkde` or `startplasma-x11`

Example for xubuntu-desktop:  `startxfce4` or `xfce4-session`

What is it for lubuntu-desktop 20.04?

Comment: I can't test this right now, but `startx` might work

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/startlxqt.1.html   Note: you've got a typo on `startxfce4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[startlxqt](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/startlxqt.1.html)**

From `man startlxqt`

> ```
>    startlxqt  is  a shell script meant to initialize and launch LXQt sessions.  It is as such
>    similar to counterparts of other desktop environments like startlxde in LXDE  or  startkde
>    in KDE.
>
>    It's main tasks are exporting environment variables, partly after performing corresponding
>    checks, and launching lxqt-session, the LXQt session manager.
>
>    It is not meant to be run by users.  Rather, it is invoked as backend,  e.  g.  by  script
>    startx on virtual terminals or display managers like SDDM or LightDM, see section EXAMPLE.
> ```

Note:  I QA-test & use Lubuntu/LXQt only locally, so I've not tested this via VPN/vnc/remotely.  This is the LXQt equivalent command to your listed examples in the question.

Comment: Maybe installing whole Lubuntu task package would be more useful - `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop^` and then use its built-in functionality.