# Connecting to Lubuntu desktop via vnc

Tags: lubuntu, vnc, lxde, tightvncserver

I have installed Lubuntu desktop on a Ubuntu 20.03 LTS server. The desktop works fine when I log on to it locally. I can see the SDDM and I can chose between various sessions for the desktop (Lubuntu, LXDE, LXQt).

However, I set up a vnc server and I configured (as per the instructions I found online) the ~/.vnc/xstartup fileto looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
xsetroot -solid grey
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
openbox &
/usr/bin/lxsession -s Lubuntu &
```

When I connect though, all I can see is a grey screen. Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You mention 20.04 & Lubuntu which is the LXQt desktop; but also LXDE (which isn't a Lubuntu desktop).  Your provided xstartup script also mentioned LXDE (which isn't Lubuntu), so are you trying to use Lubuntu or LXDE?  (Lubuntu hasn't used LXDE since 18.04)

Comment: Are you open to solutions that use VNC alternatives like RDP or x2go?

Comment: I installed Lubuntu desktop via tasksel. This seems to have enabled several options to start a session which include Lubuntu, LXQt and LXDE. What I am trying to do is start the LXQt desktop after connecting via VNC. The best advice to do this I could find online was the startup script I pasted above.

Comment: Thanks for that detail; I'll have a look (test on a *jammy* system, as LXDE is not affiliated with Lubuntu since 18.04 & thus should **not** have been included.. LXDE is now direct from upstream without any Lubuntu patching/configs).  As LXQt is WM agnostic (*no WM features are included*); Lubuntu has used `openbox` as WM and thus it's an option as a session (ie. `openbox` on its own, was back in LXDE days & is still now), but you may have described a packaging bug I'll aim to explore. `lxsession` is **not** a Lubuntu program!  https://phab.lubuntu.me/w/bugs/

Comment: I QA-test installed a Ubuntu *jammy* system on a box; then `apt install lubuntu-desktop^` and **no LXDE** packages are installed - the result is Ubuntu Desktop (GNOME) & Lubuntu (LXQT & openbox options) only.  I then repeated the test but the second time I used `sudo tasksel install lubuntu-desktop` and again **no LXDE** packages were installed.  In both I get only "Lubuntu, LXQt Desktop, Openbox, Ubuntu & Ubuntu on Xorg" options for login.   *I used jammy as I believe it'll have the same results; and if it doesn't - we can correct issues in jammy easier being currently in development*

Comment: Thanks for the investigation and the information. However, what is the command I should be using to start lubuntu desktop in the VNX server xstartup file? For example in the xfce desktop, there is a startxfce command. I don't see any startlubuntu command I can use.

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366168/what-command-will-launch-lubuntu-desktop-20-04